# Selfy number couldn't exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a positive integer $x$, let $S(x)$ denote the sum of the digits of $x$, and $l(x)$ denote the number of digits of $x$ (in base $10$). Now given a positive integer $n \ge 2$, it seems that there always exists $x$ such that $n=x+S(x)$, or $n=x+l(x)$, or $n=x+S(x)+l(x)$.

A *Selfy* number is a positive integer that can not be expressed in such a way. For example number $19$ is not Selfy because $19=14+5$; $16$ is not Selfy because $16=14+2$; and $21$ is not Selfy because $21=14+5+2$. I've checked some numbers but I couldn't find any such number.

**My question:** Is there any Selfy number?

Comment: What do you mean by "positive integer with its own number"???

Comment: its number of digits

Comment: What about the number 10?

Comment: Well, your "cannot be expressed" means that in **every** expression, the sum of digits of the number is different from the sum of digits of the expression. Have you been able to find at least **one** such expression (which wouldn't even make the number a *Selfy*, but just show that such expression exists)??? If you haven't been able to find such expression, then perhaps you should refine your question to ask if there exists a number which **can** be represented as a sum of positive numbers, such that the sum of digits of the number is different from the sum of digits of the representing sum.

Comment: ............10=9+1

Comment: To clarify your definition for other users: let $s(x)$ denote the sum of the digits of $x$, let $l(x)$ denote the number of digits of $x$. Many numbers $n$ can be expressed as $n=x+s(x)$ for some $x$. Perhaps others cannot, but they can be expressed as $n=x+l(x)$ for some $x$. A selfy number is one which can be expressed in neither form.

Comment: I,m not considered number 1 as Selfy,because number 1 is the smallest positive integer.

Comment: The question was closed, so I can't post my answer, but note that any Selfy number is of the form $10^k+k$.

Comment: @Mario,You can answer my question,so it means you understand my question well?

Comment: @GaryB Insofar as I know where to look, yes. The main difficulty is in the random behavior of $s(x)$, and I have verified that there are no Selfy numbers up to $k=4000$, i.e. any Selfy number is greater than $10^{4000}$.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\ell(x)$ is an exceptionally slow-growing increasing function, and never increases by more than $1$, so the sequence $(n+\ell(n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ increases in steps of $1$ and occasionally $2$, and so already almost all numbers are covered except those skipped over in the gaps when it increases by $2$. These are the points at which $\ell(n)$ increases, namely at $n=10^k$, at which point you have $(10^k-1)+\ell(10^k-1)=10^k-1+k$ and $10^k+\ell(10^k)=10^k+k+1$, skipping over the number $x=10^k+k$. Thus any Selfy number is of this form.

By brute-force calculation, I have verified that there are no such numbers for $k\le4000$, so we can assume that $k$ is large and so any Selfy number will have a large number of $0$'s in it separating the $10^k$ part from the $k$ part, so let's attempt to decouple the $10^k$ piece from the calculation. Since $s(x)\le 9\ell(x)$, any $x$ satisfying  $x+s(x)=10^k+k$ or $x+s(x)+\ell(x)=10^k+k$ is obviously $\le n$, so $\ell(x)\le\ell(n)=k+1$ and so $s(x),s(x)+\ell(x)\le 10(k+1)$ implying that any solution lies in the region $[10^k-9k-10,10^k+k)$.

This search area also breaks into three main regions, two for $x<10^k$ and one for $x\ge10^k$, because in the first case you have $s(x)\approx 9k$ and in the second you have $s(x)\approx 0$ (the deviations being of order $\log_{10}k$), leading to search regions near $10^k-9k$ (for $x+s(x)+\ell(x)$ solutions), $10^k-8k$ (for $x+s(x)$ solutions), and  $10^k+k$ (for $x+s(x)$ solutions). There are no $x+s(x)+\ell(x)$ solutions in the upper region because these would be larger than the $x+\ell(x)$ solutions that we have already excluded. This is the means by which the above brute-force search was performed.

Assuming $x<10^k$, we have $\ell(x)=k$, so if $x=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_i10^i$, then let $x'=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(9-a_i)10^i$. We have $x+x'=10^k-1$ and $s(x')=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(9-a_i)=9k-s(x)$, so if $x$ is a solution then we have one of
$$10^k+k=x+s(x)\implies x'+s(x')+1=8k$$
$$10^k+k=x+s(x)+k\implies x'+s(x')+1=9k$$

In the other region, $x\ge 10^k$, let $x'=x-10^k$. Then $s(x')=s(x)-1$, so
$$10^k+k=x+s(x)\implies x'+s(x')+1=k.$$

Thus we have replaced the original problem with the claim that for each (large enough) $k$ one of these three equations has a solution. Or, in the language of [self numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number):

> $10^k+k$ is a Selfy number iff $k-1,8k-1,9k-1$ are all self numbers.

---

Edit: With the help of the above reductions to eliminate the $10^k$ piece of the equation and speed up the calculation, I found a counterexample by brute force: $10^{46927}+46927$ is a Selfy number. There are also Selfy numbers for $k=47827,49728,55927,56827$ and more.

Comment: So Selfy is not impossible to exist ?

Comment: @GaryB Edit: There are Selfy numbers, I list a few.

Comment: Wow thanks Mario,you could submit it to OEIS if you want to !

Comment: It is very obvious that all Selfy numbers are also Self numbers,but the converse is not true.

Comment: Ah, now the name selfy makes more sense (never heard of self numbers before). I'm not particularly interested in having these numbers named after me - if you are motivated you can submit this to OEIS and get your own name on it. After all, as they say anyone can prove something, but making good conjectures is an art.

Comment: I've found that 10004=9968+32+4 but 10004 can not be expressed as x+s(x) nor x+l(x)

Comment: Yes, if you drop any one of the three congruences mentioned at the end, solutions become much more common, I think there are solutions within $k\le10$ for each of them. (Which is why it was surprising that all three together make it almost insoluble.)

Comment: ,I also found that 1000006 can not be expressed as x+l(x) nor x+s(x)+l(x),and if 1000006 also can not be expressed as x+s(x),then 1000006 will become a Selfy number !!

Comment: $k=4$ avoids the $k,8k$ congruences, $k=6$ avoids $k,9k$, and $k=46$ avoids $8k,9k$. Since $9k$ corresponds to $x+s(x)+l(x)$ solutions, this implies that $k=6$ is not of the form $x+l(x),x+s(x)+l(x)$. But $1000006=999962+44$ is a $x+s(x)$ decomposition for $k=6$.

Comment: I meant could you give me any number besides 1000006,which can not be expressed as x+l(x) nor x+s(x)+l(x)  ?

Comment: @GaryB Oh, I see. The next ones are at $$k=6,87,177,267,346,357,537,627,717,917,\dots$$ (A lot of $7$'s in there for some reason.)

Comment: Could you give me some numbers that can not be expressed as x+s(x) nor x+s(x)+l(x) ?

Comment: @GaryB I was expecting them to be very common, since they are not forced into the form $10^k+k$, but $1$ and $20$ are the only numbers less than $10^6$ of this type. (Of course any Selfy number is also in this list.)

Comment: Mario,why all Selfy are also in that list,since there are many numbers expressible as x+l(x) but cannot be expressed as x+s(x)+l(x) and vica versa

Comment: A Selfy number is expressible in none of those forms, so it is obviously not expressible in any subset of them. But it's not like there are many of those, as we have seen they don't start until $10^{40000}$.

Comment: Are there infinitely many numbers that can not be expressed as x+s(x) nor x+s(x)+l(x)  ?

Comment: @GaryB I figured you'd ask that question eventually. It's a good question, and possibly one I can answer, but is not addressed by the above analysis and this comment thread is getting a bit long, so I recommend you ask that in a separate question, linking back to this one. (And ping me if you do, so I can take a crack at it.)

Comment: Mario,I did that for the sake of efficiency,could you give me at least two such numbers beyond 1000000 ? please... :D

Comment: I have a theory which explains why $20$ is of this form and the next one doesn't happen until you get into the $11$-digit numbers, at which point there are many: $10^{10}+\{98,109,122,133,144,\dots\}$.

Comment: Of course all those numbers are also Self numbers ?!

Comment: @GaryB That's right. In fact, except very near the digit length boundaries $10^k$, they are the same as self numbers $n$ such that $n-\ell(n)$ is also self. (Since most self numbers differ by $11$, this explains why $11$-digit numbers are often of this form.)

Comment: Okay this is my last question,so you meant there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be expressed as x+s(x) nor x+s(x)+l(x) ?

Comment: @GaryB I meant that I need a bigger box to answer your question. Please just start a new question, it's not gonna kill you. Once you do I can clean up your english or whatever, but **you** have to ask the question.