# Does there exist a Benny number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For positive integers $x$, let $S(x)$ denote the sum of the  digits of $x$, and let $L(x)$ denote the number of digits of $x$. It can be shown that there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be expressed as $x+S(x)$ or $x+L(x)$ or $x+S(x)+L(x)$ individually or any method of those three i.e. $x+S(x)$, $x+L(x)$, and $x+S(x)+L(x)$

- [Edit note: the question this is based on, [Natural numbers not expressible as $x+s(x)$ nor $x+s(x)+l(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124488/natural-numbers-not-expressible-as-xsx-nor-xsxlx),  does not include $x+L(x)$ among the allowed formation methods].

And now a *Benny number* or *Naughty number* is a natural number greater than one that cannot be expressed as $x+S(x)$, $x-S(x)$, $x+L(x)$, $x-L(x)$, $x+S(x)+L(x)$, $x+S(x)-L(x)$, $x-S(x)+L(x)$, nor $x-S(x)-L(x)$.

I've verified that there are no Benny numbers up to $10^{20}$. My question is: Does there exist a Benny number?

Comment: $11 = 11+ s(11) - l(11) = 11 + 2 - 2$, how is that not a Benny number?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be expressed as ... any combination of those three"?  We certainly have $x=(x+S(x))+(x+L(x))-(x+S(x)+L(x))$ for all numbers $x$.

Comment: @WarmBread you might want to elaborate more than that. BarryCipra  has shown a way to express $x$ as a combination of the three, and trying to check with you if it is valid.

Comment: @graydad,I've edited my question

Comment: @graydad, I think what the OP actually means is that there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be expressed in any of the three forms, $x$, $x+S(x)$, and $x+L(x)$.  His/her question, then, is whether everything *can* be expressed by one (or more) of the *eight* forms in the second paragraph.

Comment: I meant it can be written in neither of those 8 forms

Comment: @WarmBread, if I understand things correctly, you've checked that everything up to $10^{20}$ *can* be written in one (or more) of the $8$ forms, so the question is whether there's anything that cannot.  (It might help if you edit in a proof of what you claim in the first paragraph, or give a reference of some sort.)

Comment: @BarryCipra,I think Mario Carneiro could answer this question

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right, but I think he's made it quite clear, actually. Benny numbers are those which *cannot* be represented in those $8$ forms, and he's checked that there are *no* Benny numbers up to $10^{20}$. That means that all of those numbers *can* be represented in one of the $8$ forms. It is a bit convoluted I suppose.

Comment: Yes, thanks Zubin M

Comment: @WarmBread You may have noticed that the numbers you need to check are really only those close to $10^k$ for each $k$. If a natural number $n$ is sufficiently far from any power of $10$ (for example, if its leading digit is $2$) then we can write $$L(n-L(n))=L(n)$$

If we set $x=n-L(n)$, this gives $n = x+L(x)$, which means *almost all* numbers are not Benny numbers. The other case is this:

$$L(n-L(n))=L(n)-1$$

I think this occurs exactly when $$10^k \leq n \leq 10^k + k$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee,Please contact Mario Carneiro,he will explain it :D

Comment: @MarioCarneiro - I think we would all appreciate your input to clarify this question

Comment: @BarryCipra I found the question that this was building on, [Natural numbers not expressible as x+s(x) nor x+s(x)+l(x)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124488/natural-numbers-not-expressible-as-xsx-nor-xsxlx) - note that x+L(x) was **not** an option in that problem.

Answer (score 2):

For all $n$, we either have $L(n)=L(n+L(n))$ or $L(n)=L(n-L(n))$ (or both).  If $L(n)=L(n+L(n))$, let $x=n+L(n)$.  Then

$$x-L(x)=(n+L(n))-L(n+L(n))=(n+L(n))-L(n)=n$$

Likewise, if $L(n)=L(n-L(n))$, let $x=n-L(n)$, in which case

$$x+L(x)=(n-L(n))+L(n-L(n))=(n-L(n))+L(n)=n$$

Comment: Nice solution! I'd only figured out the $L(n-L(n))$ half of this, for some reason I didn't think of the equivalent with addition. +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, thanks.  I saw your comment after I posted.

Comment: @BarryCipra,with respect,I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: @WarmBread, in that case I'm really confused as to what it means to be a Benny number.  What I just showed is that every number $n$ can be written either as $x+L(x)$ or as $x-L(x)$, which I take to imply that there are *no* Benny numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I want to explore the claim that "there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be expressed as $x+S(x)$ or $x+L(x)$ or $x+S(x)+L(x)$"

It is plain that, for most numbers $n$,  we can choose $x=n-L(n)$,  and for a few numbers after each power of $10$ we can choose $x=n-(L(n)-1)$, and then $n=x+L(x)$. In fact the only numbers which cannot be produced in this way are $n=10^k+k = \{11,102,1003,10004,\ldots\}$.

(With regard to the actual opening question, note that these can all be produced by selecting $x=10^k$ in $x-S(x)+L(x)$,  so yet another demonstration of no Benny numbers).

For $k<20$ and odd, selecting $x=10^k+(k-1)/2$ will give $n=x+S(x)$. However in general, if we can find a number $x$ such that $x+S(x)=10^k$,  then $x+S(x)+L(x)=10^k+k$. Can we always find such a number? The answer is that we can find such an $x$ with exceptions for every $10$th or so value of $k$: $\{6,16,26,36,46,57,67,77,\ldots\}$.

Usually, the pattern of numbers reached by $x+S(x)$ means that we will find *either* $x+S(x)=10^k$ *or* $x+S(x)=10^k+k$ for some $x<10^k$ for numbers up to $k=46$, . However for $n=10^{46}+46, x=n=10^{46}+36$ gives $n=x+S(x)$. Likewise for $k=77$ we also have $ x=n=10^{77}+65$ gives $n=x+S(x)$, and $k=136, 167, 257,327, 527, 597, 687,\ldots$ are similarly handled.

So if there **are** exceptions to the rule that all numbers can be reached by one of $x+L(x),x+S(x)$ or $x+S(x)+L(x)$, they are exceedingly rare. I have found none up to $10^{1000}$ for sure.